# Extracting nested XML elements of different sizes into Pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing

Lets assume we have an arbitrary XML document like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programs xmlns="http://something.org/schema/s/program">
   <program xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://something.org/schema/s/program  http://something.org/schema/s/program.xsd">
      <orgUnitId>Organization 1</orgUnitId>
      <requiredLevel>academic bachelor</requiredLevel>
      <requiredLevel>academic master</requiredLevel>
      <programDescriptionText xml:lang="nl">Here is some text; blablabla</programDescriptionText>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">Scrum master</searchword>
   </program>
   <program xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://something.org/schema/s/program  http://something.org/schema/s/program.xsd">
      <requiredLevel>bachelor</requiredLevel>
      <requiredLevel>academic master</requiredLevel>
      <requiredLevel>academic bachelor</requiredLevel>
      <orgUnitId>Organization 2</orgUnitId>
      <programDescriptionText xml:lang="nl">Text from another organization about some stuff.</programDescriptionText>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">Excutives</searchword>
   </program>
   <program xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <orgUnitId>Organization 3</orgUnitId>
      <programDescriptionText xml:lang="nl">Also another huge text description from another organization.</programDescriptionText>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">Negotiating</searchword>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">Effective leadership</searchword>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">negotiating techniques</searchword>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">leadership</searchword>
      <searchword xml:lang="nl">strategic planning</searchword>
   </program>
</programs>
```

Currently I'm `looping` over the elements I need by using their absolute paths, since I'm not able to use any of the `get` or `find` methods in ElementTree. As such, my code looks like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET   
import numpy as np
import itertools

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag

dfcols=['organization','description','level','keyword']
organization=[]
description=[]
level=[]
keyword=[]

for node in root:
    for child in 
       node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}orgUnitId'):
        organization.append(child.text) 
    for child in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}programDescriptionText'):
        description.append(child.text) 
    for child in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}requiredLevel'):
        level.append(child.text)
    for child in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}searchword'):
        keyword.append(child.text)
```

The goal, of course, is to create one dataframe. However, since each node in the XML file contains one or multiple elements, such as `requiredLevel` or `searchword` I'm currently losing data when I'm casting it to a dataframe by either:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.zip_longest(organization,
    description,level,searchword,
    fillvalue=np.nan)),columns=dfcols)
```

or using `pd.Series` as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891200/generate-a-dataframe-from-list-with-different-length) or another solution which I don't seem to get it fit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427905/extracting-data-from-xml-tree-into-pandas-csv-with-python)

My best bet is not to use Lists at all, since they don't seem to index the data correctly. That is, I lose data from the 2nd to Xth child node. But right now I'm stuck, and don't see any other options.

What my end result should look like is this:

```
organization    description  level                keyword
Organization 1  ....         academic bachelor,   Scrum master
                             academic master 
Organization 2  ....         bachelor,            Executives
                             academic master, 
                             academic bachelor    
Organization 3  ....                              Negotiating,
                                                  Effective leadership,
                                                  negotiating techniques,
                                                  ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider building a list of dictionaries with comma-collapsed text values. Then pass list into the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor:

```
dicts = []
for node in root:
    orgs = ", ".join([org.text for org in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}orgUnitId')])
    desc = ", ".join([desc.text for desc in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}programDescriptionText')])
    lvls = ", ".join([lvl.text for lvl in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}requiredLevel')])
    wrds = ", ".join([wrd.text for wrd in node.findall('.//{http://something.org/schema/s/program}searchword')])

    dicts.append({'organization': orgs, 'description': desc, 'level': lvls, 'keyword': wrds})

final_df = pd.DataFrame(dicts, columns=['organization','description','level','keyword'])
```

Output

```
print(final_df)
#      organization                                        description                                         level                                            keyword
# 0  Organization 1                       Here is some text; blablabla            academic bachelor, academic master                                       Scrum master
# 1  Organization 2   Text from another organization about some stuff.  bachelor, academic master, academic bachelor                                          Excutives
# 2  Organization 3  Also another huge text description from anothe...                                                Negotiating, Effective leadership, negotiating...
```

Comment: Although both came with a possible solution to my answer, I've got to admit that the last one works in my case. With the first answer I kept running into several errors within the function itself. The last accepted answer as a solution works neatly. 

There is, however, one small catch which is fixed easily: if the data has attributes of `NoneType` and throws an error a line could be changed to; `desc = ", ".join([str(desc.text) for desc in node.findall('.//{xml_path}Element')])`

Thanks for the support both of you

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight `xml_to_dict` converter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077069/1498199). It can be improved by [this](http://Reference:%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920989/1498199) to handle namespaces.

```
def xml_to_dict(xml='', remove_namespace=True):
    """Converts an XML string into a dict

    Args:
        xml: The XML as string
        remove_namespace: True (default) if namespaces are to be removed

    Returns:
        The XML string as dict

    Examples:
        >>> xml_to_dict('<text><para>hello world</para></text>')
        {'text': {'para': 'hello world'}}

    """
    def _xml_remove_namespace(buf):
        # Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920989/1498199
        it = ElementTree.iterparse(buf)
        for _, el in it:
            if '}' in el.tag:
                el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]
        return it.root

    def _xml_to_dict(t):
        # Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077069/1498199
        from collections import defaultdict

        d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
        children = list(t)
        if children:
            dd = defaultdict(list)
            for dc in map(_xml_to_dict, children):
                for k, v in dc.items():
                    dd[k].append(v)
            d = {t.tag: {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.items()}}

        if t.attrib:
            d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.items())

        if t.text:
            text = t.text.strip()
            if children or t.attrib:
                if text:
                    d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
            else:
                d[t.tag] = text

        return d

    buffer = io.StringIO(xml.strip())
    if remove_namespace:
        root = _xml_remove_namespace(buffer)
    else:
        root = ElementTree.parse(buffer).getroot()

    return _xml_to_dict(root)
```

So let `s` be the string which holds your xml. We can convert it to a dict via

`d = xml_to_dict(s, remove_namespace=True)`

Now the solution is straight forward:

```
rows = []
for program in d['programs']['program']:
    cols = []
    cols.append(program['orgUnitId'])
    cols.append(program['programDescriptionText']['#text'])
    try:
        cols.append(','.join(program['requiredLevel']))
    except KeyError:
        cols.append('')

    try:
         searchwords = program['searchword']['#text']
    except TypeError:
         searchwords = []
         for searchword in program['searchword']:
            searchwords.append(searchword['#text'])
         searchwords = ','.join(searchwords)
    cols.append(searchwords)

    rows.append(cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['organization', 'description', 'level', 'keyword'])
```

Comment: After looking some time at the code I can't seem to get a grip on it. So I'm wondering what kind of output Python throws at you from the `df` . In my case I'm running stuck on several name and attribute errors.

In addition, following the first link you provided I was able to pass the xml into a dictionary. However, running the `for loop` provided does not work.

Thanks for your comment, will check it out. Wasn't aware of importing another module.

Comment: You don't have to follow the link, I posted the implementation of `xml_to_dict`, too. I just wanted to make clear, that it's not "my" code.